# Creating an array as u =[0 n-1 n-2........1]

Tags: python-3.x

```
u = []
n = 3
for i in range(0,n):
    u[i] = n - i
    u.append(u[i])
print(u)
```

I am creating an array as u = [0 n-2 n-1....1]. I tried with above code and I cant find my mistake here.

Comment: u initially is a list with no item. So when you say `u[i] = n - i` before you append any new item to this list, it would result in an error.

Comment: Thank you! what is the correct version then?

Comment: That pattern doesn't make any sense. Please provide a concrete example input `n` and your expected output.

Comment: so say n=4, then I want u=[0 3 2 1]. so it the reversed is not quite doing the job.

Comment: example: let n=4, then I would like u[0]=0, u[1]=n-1, u[2]=n-2, u[3]=n-3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to generate a list from 0 to n (or from n to 0)

You're pretty close. Easier would be to convert generator from `range` directly to `list`

```py
n = 3
print(list(range(0, n)))  # [0, 1, 2]
# or for reversed
print(list(reversed(range(0, n))))  # [2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: `"It seems you want to generate a list from 0 to n (or from n to 0)"` -- I don't think so... OP's example starts with 0, and ends with 1, with a bunch of `n - x` in the middle.

Comment: Surely `list(range(n-1, 0, -1))` must be more efficient than creating the range and then running reversed on it, so the whole answer should just be `u = [0] + list(range(n-1, 0, -1))`

Comment: @DavidBuck Nice solution! That should be in answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if `i == 0` then add to `u` list. Assign `x` from `n` subtracted by 1 and `i`. `break` if `x` is equal to `0` otherwise append `x` to `u` list.

```
u = []
n = 7
for i in range(n):
    if i == 0: u += [i]
    x = n - 1 - i
    if x == 0: break
    u.append(x)

print(u)

# [0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Or:

```
n = 7
u = [0,*(range(n-1,0,-1))]
```

Comment: @mike No prob. You can also use @DavidBuck solution or `u = [0,*(range(n-1,0,-1))]`